# Firebase database rule does not work with AngularFire collection reading

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, angularfire2

I have following database rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isAdmin() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/administrators/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
    }
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /administrators/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAdmin();
    }
    match /projects/{project} {
        function getRole(rsc) {
        return rsc.data.members[request.auth.uid];
        }
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && ( getRole(resource) == 'owner' || getRole(resource) == 'participant' );
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && ( getRole(resource) == 'owner' );
    }
    match /statuses/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
  }
```

}

When I test a read of a document of collection *projects* with an authenticated userId, everything is fine.
When I try to read the same collection with AngularFire, I get error *FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.*

```
this.projectsCollection = this.afs.collection<Project>('/projects', ref =>
        ref.orderBy('projectId'));
this.projects = this.projectsCollection.valueChanges();
this.projects.subscribe(data => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    }, error => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log(error);
    })
```

Can you please help me to identify the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did read more deeply the documentation, at this link I found the issue: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters

I changed the query using a filter and the collection using an array for the memebers instead of a map object:

```
this.projectsCollection = this.afs.collection<Project>('/projects', ref =>
        ref
          .where('members', 'array-contains', this.userUid)
          .orderBy('projectId'));
```

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the members field as part of your query:

```html
this.projectsCollection = this.afs.collection<Project>('/projects', ref =>
        ref.where(`members.${this.userUid}`, 'in', ['owner', 'participant'])
        .orderBy('projectId'));
```